# How to stop adding duplicate values in select list box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to java script. I want prevent adding duplicate values to fourth list box. For example, It would not be same like below
 i) Paper Manufacturers << Paper Converters << Molded Pulp Products
 ii) Paper Manufacturers << Paper Converters << Molded Pulp Products
 And If there is no values in the fourth box, The "Remove Category" Button should be in disabled mode. If there is values & if i select any values in 4th box, The "Remove Category" Button should be enabled & "Add Category" button should be disabled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
 var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
 var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';
 var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
 var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
 var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);
 var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
 var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
 var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
 var choice = $("#tget");
 $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
  AddCategoryButtonEnable();
 });

 function getCategoryValues() {
  var firstCategoryValue = firstCategory.val();
  var secondCategoryValue = secondCategory.val();
  var thirdCategoryValue = thirdCategory.val();
  return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];
 }

 function isDisableAddButton() {
  var values = getCategoryValues();
  return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
 }

 function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
  var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
  addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
 }

 function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
  return selectedList.find("option").length;
 }

 function getAvailableChoice() {
  return 20 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
 }

 function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {
  var strText = ($numChoice !== 20) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 20 ";
   choice.text(strText);
 }

 function appendChoice() {
   var count="";
   var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues();
   if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '")').length > 0) {alert('This category has already been added.');
   return count=1;
  }
   else {
    selectedList.append('<option value="'+ givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] +'">' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '</option>');
      return count=2;
           }
  }
 addCategoryButton.click(function() {
   var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
   if (availableChoice >= 1) {
    var a=appendChoice();
    if(a==2){
    setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
    }
   } else {
    setAvailableChoice(0);
   }
  });
  var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');
  selectedList.change(function() {
   removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
   addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
   _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
  });

 function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
   removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
    selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
    var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
    if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
     setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
    } else {
     setAvailableChoice(0);
    }
    removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
   });
  }
 });
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Manufacturers</option>
  <option value="2">Paper Products Suppliers</option>
  <option value="3">Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
 </select></div>

 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Converters</option>
  <option value="2">Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
  <option value="3">Service Providers</option>
 </select></div>
 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
  <option value="1">Molded Pulp Products</option>
  <option value="2">Software Vendors</option>
  <option value="3">Information Services</option>
 </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
</select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

Comment: How to display the selected text instead of values?

Answer (score 0):

Use this script. It will show alert if try to add duplicate entry. I have changed in function appendChoice().

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
        var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
        var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';

        var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
        var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
        var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);

        var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
        var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
        var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
        var choice = $("#target");


        $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function () {
            AddCategoryButtonEnable();
        });

        function getCategoryValues() {
            var firstCategoryValue = firstCategory.val();
            var secondCategoryValue = secondCategory.val();
            var thirdCategoryValue = thirdCategory.val();
            return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];
        }

        function isDisableAddButton() {
            var values = getCategoryValues();
            return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
        }


        function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
            var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();

            addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
        }

        function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
            return selectedList.find("option").length;
        }

        function getAvailableChoice() {
            return 5 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
        }

        function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {

            var strText = ($numChoice !== 5) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 5 ";

            choice.text(strText);
        }

        function appendChoice() {
            var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues();
            if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '")').length > 0)
                alert('Duplicate value not allowed.');
            else
                selectedList.append('<option value="">' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '</option>');
        }

        addCategoryButton.click(function () {
            var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
            if (availableChoice >= 1) {
                appendChoice();
                setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
            } else {
                setAvailableChoice(0);
            }
        });

        var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');

        selectedList.change(function () {
            removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
            _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
        });

        function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
            removeCategoryButton.click(function () {
                selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
                var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
                if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
                    setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
                } else {
                    setAvailableChoice(0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the working code snippet

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
  var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
  var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';

  var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
  var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
  var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);

  var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
  var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
  var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
  var choice = $("#target");

  
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
   AddCategoryButtonEnable();
  });

  function getCategoryValues() {
   var firstCategoryValue  = firstCategory.val();
   var secondCategoryValue = secondCategory.val();
   var thirdCategoryValue = thirdCategory.val();
   return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];  
  }

  function isDisableAddButton(){
   var values = getCategoryValues();
   return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
  }


  function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
   var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
  
   addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton );
  }

  function getNumberOfSelectedOption(){
   return selectedList.find("option").length; 
  }

  function getAvailableChoice(){
   return 5 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
  }

  function setAvailableChoice($numChoice){
    
     var strText = ($numChoice !== 5) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 5 ";
      
   choice.text(strText);
  }

  function appendChoice(){
   var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues(); 
              if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '")').length > 0)
                alert('Duplicate value not allowed.');
            else
      selectedList.append('<option value="">' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '</option>'); 
  }

  addCategoryButton.click(function() {  
   var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
   if(availableChoice >= 1){
    appendChoice();
    setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
   } else {
    setAvailableChoice(0);
   }        
  });

  var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');

  selectedList.change(function(){
   removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
            addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
   _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
  });

  function _addRemoveButtonClickListener(){
   removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
    selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
    var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
    if(0 < availableChoice < 6){    
     setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
    } else {
     setAvailableChoice(0);
    }  
                removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);      
   });
  }
 });
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option>Paper Manufacturers</option>
  <option>Paper Products Suppliers</option>
  <option>Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
 </select></div>

 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
  <option>Paper Converters</option>
  <option>Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
  <option>Service Providers</option>
 </select></div>
 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
  <option>Molded Pulp Products</option>
  <option>Software Vendors</option>
  <option>Information Services</option>
 </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
</select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

Comment: Thank you Vindhyachal Kumar :) Preventing duplicate values is working fine. But i want to do these as well, If i select any value in 4th box "Remove Category" button should be enabled and "Add Category" button  should be disabled. If the values not selected and If there is no values in the 4th box  the "Remove Category" button should be disabled  i.e The "Remove Category" button should be enabled only if any values selected in the 4th box.

Comment: Thank you very much Vindhyachal Kumar :) But, Again  i'm facing problem. When click on the alert message, The count(You can add up to 5 categories) is also decreasing.